# Datatype promotion for constructors whose type could be fed literals

Tags: haskell, ghci, type-level-computation

I have a simple data type

```
data Label  = LabelK String
```

declaring :

- a type `Label` of kind `Type`
- a data constructor `LabelK` of type `String -> Label`

which I imagined would be type promoted to :

- a kind `'Label`
- a type constructor `'LabelK` of kind `forall {l :: Symbol}. Label l`

However, this does not seem to be the case, and I get instead

```
:kind 'LabelK :: String -> Label
```

So that promoted `'LabelK` is a function (?) taking a `String` as input and giving a type of kind `'Label`. I am afraid Haskell can't do that.

We can verify with

```
data Proxy (i :: k) where  
  ProxyK :: Proxy i
```

if we want to build a witness at type `'LabelK "titi"`

```
v3 = ProxyK :: Proxy ('LabelK "titi") -- fails
```

`"titi"` gets promoted to a `Symbol`, as part of [promotion of Literals](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html), and we have a type error.

---

So, **is the only way** to have a named type parameterized by a type-level string, aka a `Symbol`, to write it ourselve, as in the documentation ? :

```
data Labl (l :: Symbol) = 
   Get
```

`Get` is akin to `ProxyK` and gives us a value of type `Labl l`

```
:t Get :: forall {l :: Symbol}. Labl l
```

Then

```
Get :: Labl "x"
```

obliviates the need to build a proxy at the type index `LabelK "titi"` which we could not

---

PS : in `ghci`, one can use

```
:set -fprint-explicit-kinds
:set -fprint-explicit-foralls
```

(but we can't write `v6 = Get :: forall {l :: Symbol}. Labl l` for some reason ?)